# Jaxb not throwing exception when @XmlIDREF ref not found

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jaxb

I have a following XML:

```
  <right id="RIGHT1"/>

  <role name="User">
   <right>RIGHT1</right>
   <right>RIGHT_NOT_EXISTING</right>
  </role>
```

and here the mapping:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Role {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String name;

    @XmlIDREF
    @XmlElement(name = "right")
    private List<Right> rights;
}
```

Basically it works, the referenced existing rights are correctly found. The thing is, that I have made there an obvoius typo in the RIGHT_NOT_EXISTING reference. I would expect, that I get an exception saying "right RIGHT_NOT_EXISTING has been not found", but instead it silently ignores that one.
Is there some configuration to get that exception?

Answer (score 1):

You can try overriding the default instance of `ValidationEventHandler` on the `Unmarshaller` to see if you get the desired behaviour.  The safest thing to do would be to set an instance of `Schema` on the `Unmarshaller` to enable validation.

Comment: I didn't expect that it will be that uncommon issue... I thought wrong reference makes whole XML simply invalid, and by default should be rejected. :-(

Comment: @Tomasz - One thing we learned while developing the JAXB (JSR-222) specification is that a lot of bad XML is being passed around.  If by default this caused the XML to be rejected then nothing would ever get processed :).